# One time excuition of a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, operators

i am tracking a variale value for example 
   var d = socket.msg;

i would like to excute a notification function if the value range of the var d falls between 0 and 2.

```
function x(){
   //some codings to pop up notification
 }
```

the variable d changes at each 1 second. i would like to just run the notication function only once eventhough the var d have multiple registeration of values in the given range.

```
if(d>0  && d <2  ) {
 function x
}
```

i tried this but logically the function x will be called several times.
how to set the function o be called only once??

Answer (score 2):

You can use some kind of flag variable:

```
var called = false;
if (d > 0 && d < 2 && !called) {
  called = true;
  x();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some different options, but an easy way is to add a variable

```
var isCalled = false;

function x(){ 
    if(isCalled = false) {
         isCalled = true;
         //run code
    }
}
```

Now your code can only run once, because after the first time, isCalled is set to `true`